# table floating outside Beamer slide

Tags: tables, beamer

The problem is , I created a Table in Beamer, its not fitting in the slide, some part of it was floating outside the slide area. Any fix for this please

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. And also do you need space? If it doesn't fit what can we do? scale it?  As it is, we cannot answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try with the `\resizebox` command of the `graphicx` package.

It is not clear without a MWE if you are using really a float (a `table` environment), but probably is less troublesome use only a  non-floating `tabular` environment in beamer presentations.

Comment: `beamer` internally deactivates the floating mechanism, so you can use `table` and `figure` but they will not be teated as floats (in `beamer`).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, yes, but table still have a different behaviour by default that tabular only. For example with table will be centered instead of aligned to the left (may be causing "the floating outside" of the OP?) and could add new line and some vertical space with above-below text.

Comment: Now I see what you meant by "less troublesome".